BackgroundWorker and TreeView, stuck form when I expand TreeView
I need to create a very large TreeView, more than 200,000 nodes. The creation is fine, but the complete expansion of the TreeView, despite being executed by a different thread, sticks the form (20 - 30 seconds). Below is the stripped down code that shows only the parts involved
BackgroundWorker Expand { get; }

public Form1()
{
    Expand = new BackgroundWorker();
    Expand.DoWork += Expand_DoWork;
    .
    .
    .
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Expand.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void Expand_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Invoke(new Action(() => { treeView1.ExpandAll(); }));
}

I don't find anything wrong, maybe I should specify something in the code that I didn't specify? I thank anyone who wants to answer also because in this way I can learn from my mistakes.

A treeview with 200000 nodes is practically unusable. And there is only one UI thread

You schedule the expansion on a different thread. The expansion is still done on the UI Thread.

Invoke( is just sending it back to the UI thread anyway, in other words it's pointless to use a BackgroundWorker for this. Perhaps you can create the nodes already open?

@Steve The problem is not whether it is usable or not, after 20-30 seconds it opens and I can navigate it well. The problem is those 20-30 seconds in which the form is blocked even though I am using a different thread from the main thread.

@Fildor I'm a beginner regarding multithreading, what I don't understand is why you say "The expansion is still done on the UI Thread", given that the thread that controls the expansion is the BackgroundWorker Expand?

@Theodor Zoulias WinForms application

Combination of BackgroundWorker and Invoke is rather funny than useful. You are not using different thread.

Like I said, Invoke( marshals it back to the UI thread, and the worker just waits for that to complete. Have you tried calling ExpandAll before adding the root node to the tree?

@Charlieface Your comment is making me realize where the error potentially is. The next step is to figure out how to control the TreeView expansion from the BackgroundWorker Expand

Making control invisible to run expensive operation.. was it winforms trick? I am not sure, but try it.

You can't. UI code has to run from the UI thread, there is no other way. The best bet is to try and pre-initialize stuff, and prevent redrawing etc during the operation, as I keep saying.

"what I don't understand is why you say "The expansion is still done on the UI Thread"" - Imagine on your desk you have a pile of Files (paper) that you need to process. Then a coworker walks by and you say "Hey, can you get this one done for me, please?" and he takes it, says "Sure!" and puts it right into the pile on your desk. That's basically what above code is doing.

@Charlieface Ok thanks, I have to try to make some changes, soon I hope to post a working solution based on all the comments read here :)

@Fildor Hahaha... ok clearer than this

Have you tried calling BeginUpdate/EndUpdate on the treeview, before/after the ExpandAll? I don't have high hopes that it will make much of a difference, but you could give it a try.

@Theodor Zoulias I called BeginUpdate/EndUpdate only before and after adding the root node but I didn't use them before and after expanding. I also think it doesn't change anything but it's worth trying

Suspend/Resume Layout ... I faintly remember using those when I was dealing in WinForms ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

@Theodor Zoulias I thought nothing would change but it changed a lot! Using BeginUpdate/EndUpdate I went from waiting about 22 seconds to waiting about 4 seconds and so the situation improved a lot. Now the question I ask myself is: is it possible to make sure that even in those 4 seconds the form is not blocked? In any case, really many thanks for the suggestion.

@Fildor Mmm... your suggestion could be useful too, in fact I considered the possibility of creating the TreeView runtime from a thread that is not the main thread. But it could complicate my code a lot because I also need to manage the TV correctly, I need to be able to reset the TV and load a new one resident in memory. I think I'll try to write a solution that allows me to do all this.

How do I vote on answers?!? :(

No, I don't think that you can prevent the form from freezing for 4 seconds. Assuming that you have configured optimally the TreeView, then that's the peak performance that the built-in TreeView can give you. It was not designed to handle efficiently such a huge load. You might want to search for alternative 3rd-party TreeView controls in the market, like DevExpress or whatever. There might be UI components out there that are capable of dealing with demanding situations like this.

@Theodor Zoulias OK, thanks a lot
